# How can I normalize my results in perl with foreach control structure?

Tags: perl, normalization

I have this output:

```
10dvex2_miRNA_ce.out.data|6361
10dvex2_miRNA_ce.out.data|6361
10dvex2_misc_RNA_ce.out.data|0
10dvex2_rRNA_ce.out.data|239
```

with this script in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open(MYINPUTFILE, $ARGV[0]); # open for input
my @lines = <MYINPUTFILE>; # read file into list
my $count = 0;
print "Frag"."\t"."ncRNA"."\t"."Amount"."\n";

foreach my $lines (@lines){
my $pattern = $lines;
$pattern =~ s/(.*)dvex\d_(.*)_(.*).(out.data)\|(.*)/$1 $2   $3  $5/g;
$count += $5;
print $1."\t".$2.$3."\t".$5."\n";
}
close(MYINPUTFILE);
exit;
```

I extract this information:

```
Frag    ncRNA   Amount
10  miRNAce 6361
10  misc_RNAce  0
10  rRNAce  239
```

but in the Amount column I want to report those numbers divided by the total result (6600). In this case I want this output:

```
Frag    ncRNA   Amount
10  miRNAce 0.964
10  misc_RNAce  0
10  rRNAce  0.036
```

My problem is extract the TOTAL result in the loop...to normalize this data. Some ideas?

Comment: [`exit`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html) should really  only be used by experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( %hash, $total, %seen, @array );

while (<>) {
    next if $seen{$_}++;
    /(\d+).+?_([^.]+).+\|(\d+)$/;
    $hash{$1}{$2} = $3;
    $total += $3;
}

print "Frag\tncRNA\tAmount\n";

while ( my ( $key1, $val1 ) = each %hash ) {
    while ( my ( $key2, $val2 ) = each %$val1 ) {
        my $frac = $val2 / $total == 0 ? 0 : sprintf( '%.3f', $val2 / $total );
        push @array, "$key1\t$key2\t$frac\n";
    }
}

print map { $_->[0] }
  sort    { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
  map { [ $_, (split)[2] ] }
  @array;
```

Output from your data set:

```
Frag    ncRNA   Amount
10  miRNA_ce    0.964
10  rRNA_ce 0.036
10  misc_RNA_ce 0
```

Identical lines are skipped, and then the required elements are captured from each line.  A running total is kept for the subsequent calculation. Your desired output showed sorting from high to low, which is why each record is `push`ed onto `@array`.  However, if sorting isn't necessary, you can just print that line and omit the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) on `@array`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great solution! additionally I can control the significant numbers...Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To do this you will need two passes over the data.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

print join("\t",qw'Frag ncRNA Amount'),"\n";

my @data;
my $total = 0;

# parse the lines
while( <> ){
  my @elem = /(.+?)(?>dvex)\d_(.+)_([^._]+)[.]out[.]data[|](d+)/;
  next unless @elem;

  # running total
  $total += $elem[-1];

  # combine $2 and $3
  splice @elem, 1, 2, $2.$3; # $elem[1].$elem[2];

  push @data, \@elem;
}

# print them
for( @data ){
  my @copy = @$_;
  $copy[-1] = $copy[-1] / $total;
  $copy[-1] = sprintf('%.3f', $copy[-1]) if $copy[-1];
  print join("\t",@copy),"\n";
}
```